# Haskell : No instance for Random Point arising from a use of genRandom

Tags: haskell, random, compiler-errors

I'm getting this error for my following code that should create an array of 2 arrays which each contain 100 random points:

```
type Point = (Float, Float)

initBg :: Int -> [[Point]]
initBg seed = [genRandom 100 [] rndGen, genRandom 100 [] rndGen]
   where genRandom amt res g = if amt == 0 then res else doR0 amt res (randomR (-562, 562) g)
         doR0 amt res (a, g)  = doR1 amt res (a, randomR (-288, 288) g)
         doR1 amt res (a, (b, g))  = genRandom (amt-1) (res++[a,b]) g
         rndGen = mkStdGen seed
```

Could anyone tell me why I'm getting this error and how I can fix it?

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Best regards,
Skyfe.

EDIT: error:

```
No instance for (Random Point) arising from a use of `genRandom`
Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Random Point)
In the expression: genRandom 100 [] rndGen
In the expression:
  [genRandom 100 [] rndGen, genRandom 100 [] rndGen]
In an equation for `initBg`: 
...
```

Comment: Post the error (all of it).

Comment: And the types/classes you're referring to. And: your code would be more readable if formatted to a slightly more conventional line-width.

Comment: Updated post with error and formatted code a bit, not sure what you mean by the types/classes I'm referring to?

Comment: We have no idea what a `Point` is

Comment: @alternative: Neither seems to have the compiler, which is the reason of the error.

Comment: @user2999349: Assuming you have some kind of `data Point = Point x y`, you would need to do `Point a b : res` instead of `res++[a,b]`. Or does `randomR` generate `Point`s `a` and `b`?

Comment: Point comes from the Gloss library and is defined as (Float, Float), forgot to add its definition but I've now edited it in my post.

Comment: It looks as if an `instance (Random a, Random b) => Random (a,b) where ...` is missing in the standard libraries. I would have expected System.Random to carry it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the random class includes a `Random` class, which is a class of *values* which you can generate randomly (as opposed to what you might expect, *generators* which can make random values for you).

You can add *pairs* to the Random class by declaring:

```
instance (Random x, Random y) => Random (x, y) where
    randomR ((lo_x, lo_y), (hi_x, hi_y)) g = ((rand_x, rand_y), g'')
        where (rand_x, g')  = randomR (lo_x, hi_x) g
              (rand_y, g'') = randomR (lo_y, hi_y) g'
    random g = ((rand_x, rand_y), g'')
        where (rand_x, g') = random g
              (rand_y, g'') = random g'
```

It's a complicated definition, I know, but your code should then be able to work.

Caution: your code will cause you to generate a list [a, b] for which `a == b`, which is probably not what you want. You may want to look into the `State` monad in `Control.Monad.State.Lazy`, which you can initialize with things like:

```
state (randomR (1, 100)) :: State StdGen Int
```

This monad explicitly chains the `g` parameters for you, so:

```
ghci> :m +System.Random
ghci> :m +Control.Monad.State.Lazy
ghci> let dice_3d6 = mapM (state . randomR) (replicate 3 (1, 6)) :: State StdGen [Int]
Loading package array-0.4.0.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package deepseq-1.3.0.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package bytestring-0.10.0.2 ... linking ... done.
Loading package Win32-2.3.0.0 ... linking ... done.
Loading package transformers-0.3.0.0 ... linking ... done.
Loading package old-locale-1.0.0.5 ... linking ... done.
Loading package time-1.4.0.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package random-1.0.1.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package mtl-2.1.2 ... linking ... done.
ghci> fst $ runState dice_3d6 (mkStdGen 1)
[6,5,2]
ghci> fst $ runState dice_3d6 (mkStdGen 1)
[6,5,2]
ghci> fst $ runState dice_3d6 (mkStdGen 2)
[6,4,1]
ghci> fst $ runState dice_3d6 (mkStdGen 3)
[6,4,5]
```

In the `State StdGen` monad you can just write things like:

```
rand :: (Random r) -> (r, r) -> State StdGen r
rand (x, y) = state (randomR (x, y))

randPoint :: State StdGen (Float, Float)
randPoint = do
   x <- rand (-562, 562)
   y <- rand (-288, 288)
   return (x, y)

get100Points :: Int -> [(Float, Float)]
get100Points = fst . runState (sequence $ replicate 100 randPoint) . mkStdGen
```

which I think gives you 100 random points *without* those typeclasses above. But I am guessing at what your triple-function mutual recursion does above.